# Is there a way to handle DB response in JPA repository level

Tags: oracle, spring-data-jpa

Is there a way to handle DB response in JPA repository level,
I am using Spring data JPA and my requirement is on execution of below query all blank spaces (for LASTNAME 2nd and 4th row in STUDENT table) should get replaced by null.
I dont want to iterate the DB response in JAVA code and pad all blank spaces with null, requirement is DB itself should pad them with null on query execution. I can modify my query if required. Any help on this will be much appreciated.

```
Example: select * from STUDENT  where CITY=NEWYORK;

QUERY RESULT:

FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    CITY   

JOSEPH                  NEWYORK
MIKE        HUSSEY      NEWYORK
BOB                     NEWYORK



Desired RESULT:

FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    CITY   

JOSEPH      null            NEWYORK
MIKE        HUSSEY      NEWYORK
BOB         null            NEWYORK


STUDENT TABLE:

FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    CITY    

JACK        LARSEN      LONDON
JOSEPH                  NEWYORK
MIKE        HUSSEY      NEWYORK
BOB                     NEWYORK
```

Answer (score 0):

Uset the `trim`function to eliminate the not wanted blanks.

example

```
select '   ' LASTNAME from dual;

LASTNAME
--------

select trim('   ') LASTNAME from dual;

LASTNAME
--------
(null)
```

So select not the column `LASTNAME` but `trim(LASTNAME) as LASTNAME`.

The function remove also all leading and trailing blanks:

```
select trim('  xx yy  ') LASTNAME from dual;

LASTNAME
--------
xx yy
```

You may define a view, so that the cleaning is done transparently in the DB.

```
create view V_STUDENT as
 select 
   trim(FIRSTNAME) as FIRSTNAME, 
   trim(LASTNAME) as LASTNAME,
   trim(CITY) as CITY
from  STUDENT
```

Otherwise use the above select in your JPA query.

Comment: While executing the query we dont know which column is empty, so we want a dynamic query which can work on any column. Using case we can do so but that will be difficult if my table will have more number of columns. Is there any feature that JPA provides to achieve above?

Comment: You will get it for usre with some interceptor, but IMO this is not a good idea. Delegate simple the cleaning to the database. You need not to do it dynamically, simple trim all column.